# Java focusedProperty listener on Comment window JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to implement a listener for a comment window (stage) that I have designed that contains a textbox and two active buttons.

1. When "OK" button is pressed, the program takes the input from the
   textbox, closes the window and parses the text on another stage.
2. The "Cancel" button just closes the stage ignoring the text.

"OK" Button method:

```
    // Ok Button listener. 
    okButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {                   
            try
            {
                //Close the stage
                Stage stage = (Stage) okButton.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
                //Parse the textbox text to a singleton                    
                 TOPGun_Site_Archive_Singleton.getInstance().setAddNewCommentText(siteArchive_Comments_TextArea.getText());
            }                                
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {Logger.getLogger(Project_TOP_GUN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }                
        }                
    });
```

This is the "Cancel" button method:

```
    //Cancel Button listener
    cancelButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {                   
            try
            {
                //Close the stage
                Stage stage = (Stage) okButton.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Project_TOP_GUN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }   
        }                
    });
```

When the user clicks entirely away from the comment stage, I want to fire the "OK" button event method that I have implemented in the comment stage's controller.

I tried attaching the focus listener on the comment window's textbox, but if the user tries to click *anywhere else*, the textbox loses focus and the "OK" method is triggered.

```
    siteArchive_Comments_TextArea.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
                            {
                                if (newPropertyValue)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Textfield on focus");
                                    //do nothing


                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Textfield out focus");
                                    //If the Textfield gets out of focus, run the OK method. i.e copy the contents of the Textfield to another stage and close the comment window
                                    okButton.fire();

                                }
                            }
                        });
```

I also tried attaching the focus listener to the parent stage that is calling this comment window, but when the user clicks away from the comment stage I can't access the "OK" method inside the comment stage's controller.

```
                        // Call and open the comment stage from here 
                        // and place a listener on the comment stage itself 
                        floating_TextArea_Stage.setScene(floating_TextArea_Scene);
                        floating_TextArea_Stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
                        floating_TextArea_Stage.show(); 
                        // add the focus listener on the stage
                        floating_TextArea_Stage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
                            {
                                if (newPropertyValue)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Stage on focus");
                                    //no need to do anything here
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Stage out of focus");
                                    //this doesnot work
                                    //okButton.fire();
                                    // This doesn't work either
                                    floating_TextArea_Stage.okButton.fire()
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

I have been trying to find the best way to do it for DAYS! Have you got any ideas?

[image: my comment box stage]

Comment: Perhaps post some code?

Comment: Try to add focus listener to the comment stage. When the comment stage looses its focus trigger "OK" button.

Comment: The "OK" button, is a method inside the Comment stage controller and I don't have access to it from the stage from which I am calling the comment window.... (a bit confusing I know, did I make myself clear?)

Comment: Then can you try to add focus listener to the BorderPane.

Comment: When I attach the listener on the *textbox* and the user tries to click on "Cancel", the focus lost event runs first, so the "OK" method preceeds the "Cancel" button...
I tried adding the listener on the BorderPane, but unless I specify which node I want it on, it doesn't work! And if I DO specify that I want it on the top node, it's the same as attaching it onto the textbox itself... I even tried to add the listener onto the AnchorPane but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, try this: in the comment window controller's initialize method, get the stage the button is on and add listener like `okBtn.getScene().getWindow().focusedProperty().addListener(( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue ) ->
        {
            if (!newValue) okBtn.fire();
        });`

Comment: I tried that already but I get a javafx.fxml.LoadException exception because when the initialize method runs first time to set the listeners, there is no Window to get!

Comment: There is always a way to go :). Try adding a listener to okBtn.getScene().windowProperty() and add focus listener there after. The other way is to access to the okBtn within `floating_TextArea_Scene.lookup("#my-ok-button"); ` in your code `floating_TextArea_Stage.focusedProperty().addListener()` above.